# Record in C# with winmm.dll

Tags: c#

I want to record in my app with winmm.dll, here is my code:

```
mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

string command = "set capture time format ms bitspersample 16 channels 1 samplespersec 16000 alignment 4";
mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);
```

but format of wave file is not exactly as I set.
How i can set bit rate when record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call "set" before you call "record".

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Several properties of waveform-audio data are defined when the file to
>   store the data is created. These properties describe how the data is
>   structured within the file and cannot be changed once recording begins

As a side note; in my experience you need to set all the parameters in one go. You can't set channels alone and then set bitspersample after that. I haven't found this documented anywhere, but trial and error + google says so.

Here's how I've done it:

```
string command = "set recsound time format ms";
command += " bitspersample " + WaveBitsPerSample;
command += " channels " + WaveChannels;
command += " samplespersec " + WaveSamplesPerSec;
command += " bytespersec " + WaveBytesPerSec;
command += " alignment " + WaveAlignment;
error = mciSendString(command, _mciReturnData, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The bytespersec is relative to the bitspersample, channels and samplespersec and the alignment is relative to the bitspersample and channels.

```
bytespersec = bitspersample * channels * samplespersec / 8
alignment = bitspersample * channels / 8
```